# The sampling without replacement

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have an [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html)

```
  d = EmpiricalDistribution[{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}]
```

now, I want to sample twice without replacement $x_1,x_2$.

afterward, compute probability distribution of $|x_1-x_2|$ to get:

```
  X=|x_1-x_2|   0        1       2
      P        4/15    7/15     4/15
```

What command should be used?

Comment: d = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3}; samples=Subsets[d, {2}]; Map[{First[#], Length[#]/Length[samples]} &, Split[Sort[Map[Abs[First[#]-Last[#]]&, samples]]]] which gives you {{0, 4/15}, {1, 7/15}, {2, 4/15}}

Comment: This is a brute force algorithm. Is there a little more **simple** method?

Comment: be aware if you want to work with `EmpiricalDistribution` the second draw comes from a different distribution. Likely more complicated than Bills method

Comment: Hi tiankonghewo If your problem has more than 3 types of numbers or you need more than 3 sums then the solution that Bill gave is going to be a lot more attractive to you than the one I posted below.

Comment: Hi tiankonghewo; Always wait about 24 hours or so before accepting an answer. The first answer is not always the best and never is when it is mine. It is just to get the ball rolling and if you wait without accepting you will encourage others to answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it this way but it is a bit clumsy:

For $ \left | x2-x1 \right |=0$

```
Probability[x == 2 || y == 2 || z == 2, {x, y, z} \[Distributed]
MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[2, {3, 3, 4}]]
```

For $ \left | x2-x1 \right |=1$

```
Probability[(x == 1 && y == 1) || (y == 1 && z == 1), {x, y, z}
\[Distributed]MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[2, {3, 3, 4}]]
```

For $ \left | x2-x1 \right |=2$

```
Probability[(x == 1 && z == 1), {x, y, z}
\[Distributed]MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[2, {3, 3, 4}]]
```

Comment: Great! this is just what I need. I have learned something new. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can write this as `p[x_] = Piecewise[{Probability[#[[1]], {x, y, z} \[Distributed]  MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[2, {3, 3, 4}]], x == #[[2]]} & /@
   {{x == 2 || y == 2 || z == 2, 0},
    {(x == 1 && y == 1) || (y == 1 && z == 1), 1},
    {x == 1 && z == 1, 2}}]`

Comment: Neater and cleaner, thanks +1

Comment: OK, `Piecewise` is a new thing to me. I learned something new.

Answer (score 11):

I am a bit late but another way to use [`MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution.html):

```
md = MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[2, {3, 3, 4}];
f[{___, 2, ___}] := 0
f[{1, 0, 1}] := 2
f[{___, 1, 1, ___}] := 1
td = TransformedDistribution[
   f[{x, y, z}], {x, y, z} \[Distributed] md];
res = Probability[x == #, x \[Distributed] td] & /@ Range[0, 2]
Histogram[RandomVariate[td, 10000], Automatic, "PDF", 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]] - 1/2, #1} &, res]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is nice, I played with the Histogram command but could not make it work.+1

Comment: @bobbym thank you, your answer got to the guts of the matter (reciprocal +1). I just wanted to show another way to use `MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution` :)

Comment: This method is more simple and convenient.

Comment: @tiankonghewo please do not feel compelled to accept my answer. I think `MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution` was the key insight and bobbym and all our subsequent answers.  I do thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

Amplifying on answer by @bobbym

```
p[x_] = Piecewise[{Probability[#[[1]], {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
       MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[2, {3, 3, 4}]], 
     x == #[[2]]} & /@
   {{x == 2 || y == 2 || z == 2, 0},
    {(x == 1 && y == 1) || (y == 1 && z == 1), 1},
    {x == 1 && z == 1, 2}}]
```

[image]

The distribution for `|x1-x2|` is then

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[p[x], {x, 0, 2, 1}];
```

This distribution can be used like any other distribution

```
PDF[dist, x] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
CDF[dist, x]
```

[image]

```
Mean[dist]

(*  1  *)

Variance[dist]

(*  8/15  *)

SeedRandom[1]

RandomVariate[dist, 10]

(*  {2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}  *)
```

Comment: instructive amplification  +1 (`TransformedDistribution` also works nicely in this case)

Answer (score 4):

in case you wanted to work with `EmpericalDistribution` :

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3};
outcomes = Tuples[ConstantArray[Union[list], 2]]
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 
>     3}}

```
{Abs[Subtract @@ #], PDF[EmpiricalDistribution[list], #[[1]]]  
     PDF[EmpiricalDistribution[
       Drop[list, First@Position[list, #[[1]]]]], #[[2]]] } & /@ 
  outcomes;
{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[%, First]
```

> {{0, 4/15}, {1, 7/15}, {2, 4/15}}

of course , `PDF[EmpiricalDistribution[list], i]` just gives you `Count[list,i]/Length@list`